# Multiples of n is a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Language of the values of an affine function](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/640/language-of-the-values-of-an-affine-function)

Let $C_n = \{x\mid x \text{ is a binary number that is a multiple of } n\}$. Show that for each $n$, the language $C_n$ is regular.

Just provide a generic recipe (i.e., a formal definition for arbitrary $n$).

Comment: possible duplicate http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/640/157 ?

Comment: Yes, that question is the same but for decimal rather than binary. But my answer started with binary and then derived decimal from that, so it's also an answer to this one (as are the other answers, in effect).