# How do you prove that the set of decimal representation of the 4 divisble natural numbers is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, proof-techniques

This is from an old exam, the last Task no one could solve correctly and I'm curious how it's done :p

Show that the set of decimal representation (without leading zeroes) of the divisible numbers by `4` (natural numbers) is regular.

By this thread [How to prove a language is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular) I know that one can make a DFA to Show that a language is regular.

But is that possible at all because we have infinite natural numbers that are divisible by `4`..

I cannot even imagine how that DFA would look like :o

Maybe there is another way of showing this, too?

**Edit**: Removed..

Comment: First answer how would a number divisible by 4 look like in binary. Hint: assuming that first input bit is LSB, the minimal DFA has only 3 states.

Comment: @rus9384 I think I understand your hint but will Need 4 states. Could you check it if I edit my question in about 20 minutes?

Comment: Well, if there are 4 states, it's not minimal (even if first bit is MSB). Accepting state can have transitions to non-accepting states.

Comment: This is a special case of https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/640/language-of-the-values-of-an-affine-function

Comment: @Gilles Please check my edit

Comment: @cnmesr We don't check people's work. That's what your TA is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A decimal number is divisible by 4 if the number formed by its last two digits are divisible by 4. Stated differently, divisibility by 4 depends only on the last two digits. That should be enough for you to show that your language is regular.

[The language of numbers in base $b$ divisible by $m$ is regular for all $b,m$, but that's somewhat harder to show.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/640/language-of-the-values-of-an-affine-function)

Comment: Can you please check my Edit? I've used your explanation and the given link and had created it like that. But I don't know how to continue :s I hope the part I created is correct at least?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot replace your TA.